# How to track down if someone uses torrent in local network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, bittorrent

We have a router , i have an admin password for his interface, so i can monitor LAN activity.
But how can i be sure if some user behind some ip is using torrent?

Router runs on AirOS from Ubiquiti Networks , using latest firmware (updated 2 weeks ago).

Answer (score 1):

From the router it could a bit awkward since if the router doesn't support protocol dissection (or L7 filtering) you would need to put some rules to specific ports/hosts (for example torrent servers) and see if they match. But this is for sure not the way to do it since it is long and would not have a complete match.

AirOS has some P2P blocking capabilities: check in Firewall Policies -> Advanced -> you can disable some P2P services. But there are very basic (mostly on DNS level)

Most probably the fastest way is to attach into the network with a packet sniffer such as [Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/FrontPage) which has already protocol dissection for [BitTorrent](http://wiki.wireshark.org/BitTorrent). But again it depends on the torrent user aswell if he is using just encrypted peers or hiding services.

Comment: Considering you can setup a BitTorrect client to work on any port what you describe about blocking certain ports is unlikely to be effective.

Comment: What I suggested in first place, and specified that it is not a complete solution, is to match the access to torrent *servers* (that is trackers). That have, at least the famous and most used ones, quite specific and "stable" addresses/ports. Of course this will just trigger when the client is fetching the peers lists and will not work for some cases (such as usage of the DHT network)

Comment: I don't want to ban using torrent network in our local place, because sometimes it is ok to download some useful things. I want to know who are using it most and limit their speed rates or something.

Comment: @RuslanVoronkov - QOS and DPI exists for that purpose. To use both in the combination you describe requires specialized hardware though.